# org.apache.commons.mail,version=[1.3,2) -- Cannot be resolved issue in CQ5(AEM)

Tags: java, maven, email, servlets, aem

I want to send email from Adobe CQ5 using Eclipse Maven multi-module project. My idea was to create a servlet to write the code for mail functionality and after that to call that servlet in a form component to provide inputs and fire the mail to the admin.So I have created a servlet in my Eclipse project and have followed all the steps from [this tutorial](http://www.albinsblog.com/2014/12/sending-mail-through-java-api-with_17.html#.VReTh_mUdPM), which suggested the following JARs:

```
import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.day.cq.mailer.MessageGateway;
import com.day.cq.mailer.MessageGatewayService;
```

I can see the build is successful and the package is installed in http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles. But in System/console/bundle the package is in **installed** state, not in **active** state which cannot  be used.

To verify the issue when I expanded it, I am getting this error:

```
org.apache.commons.mail,version=[1.3,2) -- Cannot be resolved.
```

The full description of the package is:

```
Exported Packages   aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core,version=1.0
Imported Packages   aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core,version=[1.0,1.1) from aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core (408)
com.day.cq.mailer,version=[5.8,6) from com.day.cq.cq-mailer (267)
javax.jcr,version=[2.0,3) from org.apache.sling.jcr.jcr-wrapper (106)
javax.mail.internet,version=[1.4,2) from javax.mail (178)
javax.servlet from org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api (29)
org.apache.commons.mail,version=[1.3,2) -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.sling.api,version=[2.3,3) from org.apache.sling.api (184)
org.apache.sling.api.request,version=[2.4,3) from org.apache.sling.api (184)
org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=[2.5,3) from org.apache.sling.api (184)
org.apache.sling.api.servlets,version=[2.1,3) from org.apache.sling.api (184)
org.apache.sling.commons.osgi,version=[2.2,3) from org.apache.sling.commons.osgi (56)
org.apache.sling.jcr.api,version=[2.2,3) from org.apache.sling.jcr.api (104)
org.apache.sling.settings,version=[1.3,2) from org.apache.sling.settings (13)
org.osgi.service.event,version=[1.2,2) from org.apache.felix.eventadmin (51)
org.slf4j,version=[1.5,2) from slf4j.api (14)
Manifest Headers    Bnd-LastModified: 1427608012083
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_71
Built-By: ajena
Bundle-Description: Core bundle for flightdeck
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: flightdeck - Core
Bundle-SymbolicName: aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core
Bundle-Version: 1.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Export-Package: aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core; version="1.0"
Import-Package: aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core; version="[1.0, 1.1)", com.day.cq.mailer; version="[5.8, 6)", javax.jcr; version="[2.0, 3)", javax.mail.internet; version="[1.4, 2)", javax.servlet, org.apache.commons.mail; version="[1.3, 2)", org.apache.sling.api; version="[2.3, 3)", org.apache.sling.api.request; version="[2.4, 3)", org.apache.sling.api.resource; version="[2.5, 3)", org.apache.sling.api.servlets; version="[2.1, 3)", org.apache.sling.commons.osgi; version="[2.2, 3)", org.apache.sling.jcr.api; version="[2.2, 3)", org.apache.sling.settings; version="[1.3, 2)", org.osgi.service.event; version="[1.2, 2)", org.slf4j; version="[1.5, 2)"
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Provide-Capability: osgi.service; effective:=active; objectClass="java.lang.Runnable"; scheduler.expression="*/30 * * * * ?"; scheduler.concurrent=false; service.vendor=Adobe
Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))"
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core.impl.schedulers.SimpleScheduledTask.xml, OSGI-INF/aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core.impl.listeners.SimpleResourceListener.xml, OSGI-INF/aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.xml, OSGI-INF/aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core.impl.servlets.EmailServlet.xml, OSGI-INF/aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core.impl.HelloServiceImpl.xml, OSGI-INF/aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core.impl.servlets.SimpleServlet.xml
Tool: Bnd-2.3.0.201405100607
```

When I checked the error.log file of AEM author  I am getting the error message below:

```
29.03.2015 11:16:55.235 *INFO* [FelixDispatchQueue] org.apache.felix.framework FrameworkEvent PACKAGES REFRESHED
29.03.2015 11:16:55.235 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.tasks.BundleStartTask Could not start bundle aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core [408]. Reason: {}. Will retry.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core [408]: Unable to resolve 408.96: missing requirement [408.96] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.mail)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3980)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2043)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.tasks.BundleStartTask.execute(BundleStartTask.java:93)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.OsgiInstallerImpl.executeTasks(OsgiInstallerImpl.java:733)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.OsgiInstallerImpl.run(OsgiInstallerImpl.java:247)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
29.03.2015 11:16:55.275 *INFO* [OsgiInstallerImpl] org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.tasks.BundleStartTask Could not start bundle aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core [408]. Reason: {}. Will retry.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle aem.flightdeck.com.flightdeck.core [408]: Unable to resolve 408.96: missing requirement [408.96] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.mail)(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3980)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2043)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.tasks.BundleStartTask.execute(BundleStartTask.java:93)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.OsgiInstallerImpl.executeTasks(OsgiInstallerImpl.java:733)
    at org.apache.sling.installer.core.impl.OsgiInstallerImpl.run(OsgiInstallerImpl.java:247)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In my POM.xml file I have added the dependency as below:

```xml
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In the dependency folder which is - .m2\repository\commons-email\commons-email folder, the commons-email 1.3.2.jar is already downloaded.

Can anyone share any suggestions for fixing this issue, or suggest how I can send email from CQ5 component on a button click without using workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your quick response!
 I got the soltuion.
 I even had tried to install the jars directly in console but it didnt help.
I simply changed the dependancy version to 1.2 as mentioned below and it worked

```
<dependency>    
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK This is the error due to your dependency is not on the CQ Server, It is in you local but not on the CQ Server. One thing you can try out. Download this dependency or If you already has in your .m2 folder. Install it under bundes from http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles same as you do with bundles. There can be also other way in maven you can send this dependency to CQ server along with build, for this you need to check different scopes under dependency we can use.

Thanks